# Active datanode not displayed by namenode

Tags: hadoop, nodes

I have a hadoop cluster with 1 name node and 4 data nodes, and the replication value in HDFS-site.xml was set to 3. I recently replaced a data node machine and restarted the cluster. SSH from name node to any data node was set up to use passwordless login, and the firewall on the new data node was also turned off. The cluster works fine. However, the name node only displays 3 data nodes with the newly added data node missing. What's interesting is that JPS displays that DataNode and TaskTracker processes are running on the data node that is not being displayed by the name node. What could be wrong? Thanks!

Update: Just found out that the core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml on the problematic node were pointing to wrong namenode host. After correcting these values and restarting the cluster, all the data nodes are being displayed by the cluster summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the conf\slaves file on the name node box. It lists datanodes - you may want to ensure that newly added datanode is found there.
Pls restart the name node too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The new data node was already listed in the slaves file. I guess, otherwise, the DataNote and TaskTracker processes on the new data node won't be started.

Comment: Yes, I did restart the name node.

Comment: As a test, I just stopped the cluster from the name node again. What's interesting was that the terminal shows that no tasktracker and no data node to stop on the new data node. However, when I restarted the cluster, no error was logged for the problematic data node. And even the tasktracker log file was generated without problem. Again, JPS on the new data node still shows TaskTracker and DataNode processes are running, but the cluster summery doesn't display this new data node.

Comment: Just re-stopped the cluster from the name node, the terminal shows tasktracker and datanode processes were stopped on all the data nodes, including the problematic one. After re-start, the new data node is still missing from the cluster summery, although the datanode and tasktracker processes are running on all the data nodes. I am so confused.

Comment: is the new DN blocked by firewall or port restrictions from reaching the NN...another thing to check

Comment: No, firewall was turned off already. I have figured out that the issue was caused by wrong host settings in core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml on the name node. See the update section in my original post. Thanks!